# Assign only required properties of an Input Object in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a generic component, with an input of 'padding'

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'scheme-details',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgIf],
  templateUrl: './scheme-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scheme-details.component.scss']
})
export class SchemeDetailsComponent {
  @Input() icon: string | undefined = undefined
  @Input() name: string = ""
  @Input() tags: string[] = []
  @Input() padding: { top: string; bottom: string } = { top: "0px", bottom: "0px" }

}
```

I know we can assign only required styles in template like this

```
<div [style.paddingTop]="'10px'"> Content </div>
```

Similarly, I want to achieve this format in my template but I couldn't find a workaround

```
<scheme-details [icon]="icon" [name]="name" [tags]="[]" [padding.top]="'10px'" />
```

NOTE: This is not an Issue, I'm just exploring if this is achievable, And I appreciate the time you spent for my question, Thanks

I have tried changing types of the padding input but it always gave me an error "Can't bind to 'padding.top' since it isn't a known property of 'scheme-details'", which seems to be correct

Comment: Have you tried `[padding]="{ top: '10px', bottom: '0px' }"`?

Comment: yes, it works. I just want to know if this ```[padding.top]="'10px'"``` is possible, because it does work in single style binding as mentioned in their doc [binding-to-a-single-style](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#binding-to-a-single-style)

Comment: you meant like [style.paddingTop]="padding.top" and  [style.paddingBottom]="padding.bottom"?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly you're looking for, but you can use some like

```
  _padding: { top: string; bottom: string } = { top: '', bottom: '' };
  @Input()
  set padding(c: Partial<{ top: string; bottom: string }>) {
    this._padding = {...this._padding, ...c}
  }
  get padding() {
    return this._padding;
  }
```

And use like

```
 <app-child [padding]="{top:'1px'}"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you assign some static value, however we can't do use property binding with this approach.

**component.ts**

```
import { Attribute, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'scheme-details',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgIf],
  template:`
  {{padding.top}}
  `,

})
export class SchemeDetailsComponent {
  @Input() icon: string | undefined = undefined
  @Input() name: string = ""
  @Input() tags: string[] = []
  @Input() padding: { top: string; bottom: string } = { top: "0px", bottom: "0px" }

  constructor(@Attribute('padding.top') public paddingTopValue:string){
    if(this.paddingTopValue){
      this.padding.top = this.paddingTopValue;
    }
  }

}
```

**[For More Info About Attribute Decorator](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-attribute-decorator-in-angular-4f7c9fb61243)**

**[Working Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-p3ycu7?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**